# ImportError: cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_ using H2O GPT

Tags: python-import, python-3.10, urllib3, h2ogpt

I am trying to run H2O GPT locally using my conda environment and the following command

```
python3 generate.py \
  --base_model=h2oai/h2ogpt-gm-oasst1-en-2048-falcon-7b-v3 \
  -score_model=None \
  --load_4bit=True \
  --prompt_type=human_bot \
  --share=False \
  --gradio_offline_level=1
```

it used to work properly but after an update I get the following error:

```
Auto set langchain_mode=LLM.  Could use MyData instead.  To allow UserData to pull files from disk, set user_path or langchain_mode_paths, and ensure allow_upload_to_user_data=True
Using Model h2oai/h2ogpt-gm-oasst1-en-2048-falcon-7b-v3
Prep: persist_directory=db_dir_UserData exists, using
Starting get_model: h2oai/h2ogpt-gm-oasst1-en-2048-falcon-7b-v3 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/programs/h2ogpt/generate.py", line 16, in <module>
    entrypoint_main()
  File "/home/user/programs/h2ogpt/generate.py", line 12, in entrypoint_main
    H2O_Fire(main)
  File "/home/user/programs/h2ogpt/src/utils.py", line 60, in H2O_Fire
    fire.Fire(component=component, command=args)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 141, in Fire
    component_trace = _Fire(component, args, parsed_flag_args, context, name)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 475, in _Fire
    component, remaining_args = _CallAndUpdateTrace(
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 691, in _CallAndUpdateTrace
    component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/programs/h2ogpt/src/gen.py", line 1052, in main
    model0, tokenizer0, device = get_model(reward_type=False,
  File "/home/user/programs/h2ogpt/src/gen.py", line 1408, in get_model
    config, _, max_seq_len = get_config(base_model, **config_kwargs, raise_exception=False)
  File "/home/user/programs/h2ogpt/src/gen.py", line 1119, in get_config
    from accelerate import init_empty_weights
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .accelerator import Accelerator
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/accelerator.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .checkpointing import load_accelerator_state, load_custom_state, save_accelerator_state, save_custom_state
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/checkpointing.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .utils import (
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/utils/__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    from .launch import (
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/utils/launch.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ..commands.config.config_args import SageMakerConfig
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/commands/config/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .config import config_command_parser
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/commands/config/config.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .sagemaker import get_sagemaker_input
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/commands/config/sagemaker.py", line 35, in <module>
    import boto3  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 26, in <module>
    import botocore.client
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 15, in <module>
    from botocore import waiter, xform_name
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 18, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.docstring import WaiterDocstring
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/docs/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.service import ServiceDocumenter
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/docs/service.py", line 14, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.client import ClientDocumenter, ClientExceptionsDocumenter
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/docs/client.py", line 17, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.example import ResponseExampleDocumenter
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/docs/example.py", line 13, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.shape import ShapeDocumenter
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/docs/shape.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.utils import is_json_value_header
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 37, in <module>
    import botocore.httpsession
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 22, in <module>
    from urllib3.util.ssl_ import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (/home/user/anaconda3/envs/h2ogpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)
```

so basically it cannot import DEFAULT_CIPHERS from `urllib3.util.ssl`.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I edited `requirements.txt` as pointed here](https://community.openai.com/t/openai-cannot-import-name-default-ciphers-problem-breaking-changes-with-the-latest-version-of-requests/194265), so I changed `urllib3>=1.26.16` to `urllib3==1.26` in `requirements.txt` and then ran

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It changed the version of the urllib3 and then it worked.